# Apply color to Pie Chart slices in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, visualization, excel-2007, pie-chart

I want to create a pie chart in Excel with 33 pieces.

I want for each piece, depending on the value of the cell
green (No issue)
red (Need)
yellow (Opportunity)

For example,
Identifier #       Results
1                  No issue
2                  Opportunity
3                  Need
...
33

I created a regular pie chart but it is tedious to individually change the color on each slice.

I would like the color of the slice to be automated.

Comment: Jon Peltier's site has a wealth of information on Excel charts. [This page](https://peltiertech.com/conditional-formatting-of-excel-charts/) discusses how conditional formatting may help. You might also check out setting colors [by category](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-bar-chart-change-color-based-on-category/) as well.

Comment: Could you share how your data looks like, and maybe a screenshot of your current chart?

Answer (score 0):

A pie chart may not be the best choice. It's not easy to label 33 slices clearly. Labeling in a horizontal bar chart will work much better, and the bar chart will probably take up less space and still be legible.

[image: Pie and Bar Charts Conditionally Formatted by VBA]

The code below works on either chart type.

```
Sub ColorByValue()
  If Not ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    With ActiveChart
      Dim srs As Series
      Set srs = .SeriesCollection(1)
      Dim vals As Variant
      vals = srs.Values
      Dim iPt As Long
      For iPt = 1 To UBound(vals)
        Select Case vals(iPt)
          ' select your cutoff values and colors
          Case Is >= 8
            srs.Points(iPt).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 5287936 ' vbGreen
          Case Is <= 3
            srs.Points(iPt).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
          Case Else
            srs.Points(iPt).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 49407 ' vbYellow
        End Select
      Next
    End With
  Else
    MsgBox "Select a chart to format!", vbExclamation, "No Active Chart"
  End If
End Sub
```